# Display specific data on Data Grid from File Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a part of program that when user A login, A have capability to editing Profile like Name, and Password. The profile data will display on data grid (the source in file txt).

But i don't know why the data won't display, here's my text file: (col : name, employee ID, password)

```
admin#EMP001#iamadmin#
staff#EMP002#iamstaff#
```

And here's my code, which is getting the data based on EmployeeID.

```
public void viewDataProfil()
        {
            string line, search;
            string[] strArray = new string[3];
            Boolean find = false;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "User Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "EmployeeID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Password";
            F = new FileStream("Login.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            R = new StreamReader(F);
            search = lblEmployeeID.Text; //in lblEmployeeID.Text, i'm using another method that getting data form file txt also
            while ((line = R.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                int stringStartPos = line.IndexOf('#');
                if (search.Equals(line.Substring(0, stringStartPos)))
                {
                    find = true;
                    strArray = line.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    txtUserName.Text = strArray[0];
                    lblEmployeeID.Text = strArray[1];
                    txtPassword.Text = strArray[2];
                    dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = strArray[0];
                    dataGridView1[1, 0].Value = strArray[1];
                    dataGridView1[2, 0].Value = strArray[2];
                }
            }
            if (!find)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry data not found!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            R.Close();
            F.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in the debugger to see where the issue lies? Is the if statement `if (search.Equals(line.Substring(0, stringStartPos)))` ever equating to true?

Comment: You mean added `== true` on condition?. the result it's same.

Comment: No, does the statement `search.Equals(line.Substring(0, stringStartPos))` _evaluate_ to true? Have you used the debugger to step through to make sure the variables are being assigned the proper values as you expect? I ask becuase I suspect that either A) the if statement is evaulating to false and not proceeding to add the data to your datagridview, B) strArray is not being populated as you expect, or C) R is null.

Comment: I dont really think all of your suspect is right, i'm sorry because english is not my native language so i a little bit didn't understand your explanation :( okay back to problem, but the program can run if i switch column User name and EmployeeID,